# Visual Studio 2012 silverlight debugger doesn't work

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a Silverlight project with a team. All of a sudden my debugger was working weirdly.

It doesn't attach to the browser when the application shows up, so I need to launch debug again, therefore when I refresh the first browser window the debugging works normally.

My colleagues don't have this problem, so I've created a new empty silverlight project, and the problem still appears...

I have installed update 2, the plugins I have are resharper and ankhsvn. I've uninstalled them and nothing changed.

If you have any idea, you are very welcome.

Comment: Do you use a web project for your silverlight application?

Comment: Yes I do, and the silverlight debugging is checked in the project options

Comment: I recommend you to use Internet Explorer as a default browser for debugging. Have you checked IE?

Comment: Ok so I just reinstalled visual studio. IE is the default browser. Still stuck...